# JSON from AJAX to PHP server. Remembering data types

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Is it possible to send JSON data from the client side using ajax (with jQuery), to a PHP page and use json_decode with all the variables exactly the same data type? I thought JSON was suppose to preserve this but it seems it doesn't work if you send it to PHP. If it doesn't do this then I'm not sure why I should ever be using JSON. I might as well just use a standard POST request.

My problem is that I need to send data to PHP for it to be inserted into MySQL which requires the right variable types being inserted, but when the data arrives from JSON it is all converted to a string. I think I'm misunderstanding what JSON is suppose to be used for. Most likely, and if so can anyone explain this to me?

Does this mean I need to manually convert everything on the PHP side all the time throughout my entire web application? That would be a real pain.

```
// JavaScript:

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "program.php",

    data: {
        posting: true,
        json: JSON.stringify({
            posting: true,
            id: 6,  // should remain an integer
        })
    },

    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});


// PHP:

if (array_key_exists("posting", $_POST)) {
    $result = json_decode($_POST["json"]);
    echo gettype($result->id); // string (all values in $result are strings still)
    exit();
}
```

EDIT: The reason I'm worried about variable types is because I am trying to use prepared statements with MySQL and the bind_param function requires you to enter the variable types. This is a PHP function I created to handle this for me:

```
public static function insert($query, $params) {        
    $statement = mysqli_prepare(self::$connection, $query);
    foreach ($params as $value) {
        switch (gettype($value)) {
            case "boolean":
                $value = (int) $value;
            case "integer":
                $statement->bind_param("i", $value);
                break;
            case "double":
                $statement->bind_param("d", $value);
                break;
            case "string":
                // it is ALWAYS a string even though some as suppose to be integers
                $statement->bind_param("s", $value);
                break;
            default: 
                echo "error type: " . gettype($value);
                return;
        }
    }

    $statement->execute();
    $statement->fetch();
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    $statement->close();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Couple of questions... 1. How does it being a string prevent it from inserting/updating? 2. `POST` requests are made in to strings within the `$_POST` array as well, so how would that be any different?

Comment: @Jon Well I need to use prepared statements so do I just always use "bind_param" and specify everything as a string?

$statement->bind_param("s", $value);

Comment: @Jon I've added more to the post. Hope that answers your question. I'm confused about the need for any JSON related stuff on the client side any more because every time I look into this online, everyone says just use a post request so I have no clue.

Comment: Depending on if using `mysqli` or `pdo`, this may differ. I use PDO, and I bind on execute. ie. `UPDATE users SET fullName=:fullName WHERE id=:id` and when I execute, I pass an array like `array('fullName' => $_POST['fullname'], 'id' => $_POST['id'])` (or use the decoded json instead of post, but works the same)

Comment: Hmm, using `mysqli` I am not too familiar with, but I don't believe you'll run in to problems binding them as strings instead. JSON has it's uses, but for something like this, `post` would be a better way to go about it.

Comment: @Jon Sounds like JSON is completely useless in this scenario like I feared then. I may just have to manually convert everything each time I want to use my PHP insert function.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with what the JSON developers failed to mention in their specification: **JSON is actually JSON when it's used in a string context.**

Think logically with me here. How are you going to transfer the data type information? The rational thing would be to mark it somehow. Well, JavaScript does that while it holds your not-so-JSON-yet as an object. But since `$_POST` uses only *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* or *multipart/form-data*, you end up with the string or binary data anyway.

But at this state it's not possible to save and transfer data types inside your *string* json, not until you specify data types directly in your JSON as this:

```
{"name": "Food", "value": "Banana", "type": "string"},
{"name": "Drink", "value": "Beer", "type": "string"},
{"name": "Count", "value": "42", "type": "int"}
```

And then parse it in PHP. Or punch in the required data types for `bind_param` directly and just use it after decoding JSON.

Oh, and yeah, **`stringify`** somehow speaks for itself:

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON ***string***, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

Further reading:

- [PHP Post Variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)
- [W3C Form Content Types](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4)
- [jQuery .ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [Ben Alman on JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)
- [MDN on JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Thank you, that helps. I tried editing the ajax function using "contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"," but that didn't really change anything either even though I thought it would. I'll just try adding in the data types manually then.

Answer (score -1):

If you're still getting stuck with this I have done a basic example that covers the HTML/JavaScript using Jquery and the PHP page (logging data to a text file)

**JavaScript Code - Index.html**

```
<a href="#" class="button">Submit</a>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(".button").on("click", function(){
        ajaxSubmit();
    });

    var ajaxSubmit = function(){

        var obj = {};

        obj['foo'] = {};
        obj['foo']['type'] = 'integer';
        obj['foo']['value'] = 1;

        obj['bar'] = {};
        obj['bar']['type'] = 'string';
        obj['bar']['value'] = 'hello';

        sendData = JSON.stringify(obj);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "program.php",
            data: {'json': sendData},

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    };

</script>
```

**PHP Code - program.php**

```
<?php

    $data = $_REQUEST;

    $obj = json_decode($data['json']);

    foreach ($obj as $var) {

        switch ($var->type) {
            case 'integer':
                fileWrite('Integer: '.$var->value);
                break;
            case 'string':
                fileWrite('String: '.$var->value);
                break;
        }

    }

    function fileWrite ($string) {

        if (is_array($string)){
            $string = 'Array: '.print_r($string, true);
        }

        if(is_object($string)) {
            $string = 'Object: '.print_r($string, true);

        }

        $fp = fopen('output.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, $string."\n");
        fclose($fp);

    }

?>
```

Comment: I'm not actually using a form so no. Thanks though.

Comment: I made an update, seems to me that it should work. Maybe I am misunderstanding your requirements?

Comment: @Mark I actually have tried that but on the PHP page it says that $_POST is empty so no data gets transferred.

Comment: Sorry Jon, I was on a tangent, I made an adjustment, making the objects more complex, should be able to foreach item and just grab its type as well as its value from the object. Let me test it quickly.

Comment: I was able to get this script to work by using "GET" as the type, I have the PHP script receiving and logging the data now

Comment: I updated my answer to a tested version, doesn't put anything into the database but should be a good framework for this kind of ajax requests.